# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake, clang, dylib

I am attempting to compile this library on mac os x Mavericks 10.9.3 64-bit: http://www.openfec.org/downloads.html

I followed the README exactly, and got this error:

> Linking C shared library ../../bin/Release/libopenfec.dylib
>
> ```
>    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>       "_of_add_from_multiple_symbols", referenced from:
>          _of_linear_binary_code_backward_substitution in of_ml_tool.c.o
>       "_of_add_to_symbol", referenced from:
>          _of_linear_binary_code_decode_with_new_symbol in of_it_decoding.c.o
>          _of_linear_binary_code_simplify_linear_system in of_ml_decoding.c.o
>          _of_linear_binary_code_col_forward_elimination_pivot_reordering in of_ml_tool.c.o
>          _of_linear_binary_code_apply_gauss_pivoting in of_ml_tool_2.c.o
>          _of_linear_binary_code_inject_symbol_in_triangular_system in of_ml_tool_2.c.o
>          _of_linear_binary_code_solve_triangular_system in of_ml_tool_2.c.o
>          _of_linear_binary_code_invert_dense_system in of_ml_tool_2.c.o
>          ...
>       "_of_calloc", referenced from...:
>          ...
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make[2]: *** [../bin/Release/libopenfec.dylib] Error 1
>
>   make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/openfec.dir/all] Error 2
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

I simply followed the README for OpenFEC's distro (found at http://www.openfec.org/downloads.html). When attempting to make, this error arises.
I have no idea what the problem is.

This is what I did after untarring the distribution:
(1.): mkdir build
(2.): cd build
(3.): cmake .. -DDEBUG:STRING=OFF
(4.): make

Any ideas?

Edit: Attempted to force cmake to use 64-bit, still didn't work.
(Tried to force it into 32-bit just for kicks, also didn't work)

Comment: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" means that the library is built for some other architecture. The library target architecture could be 32 bit(i.e. i386). Find out how to build this library for 64 bit architecture(x86_64).

Comment: Can you just have look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334095/cmake-multiarchitecture-compilation) on compiling in 64 bit architecture using cmake.

Comment: I did, and I attempted it. Unfortunately that did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, if this wasn't resolved. Check that you're linking to your libraries properly.

```
FIND_LIBRARY(LIB_NAME_LIB lib)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_executable ${LIB_NAME_LIB})
```

In your CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: I am new to CMake, so I need a little help here.  I'm getting Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 for boost.  I am using CLion, which uses Cmake.  This is what I have at the bottom of my CMakeLists.txt file:

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost 1.55.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem thread chrono system atomic program_options)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(Oneprint ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(Oneprint ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(Oneprint ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

How would I use your above suggestion (actual name or alias)?